# GNU make doesn't include headerfile

Tags: c, embedded, gnu-make

I have been searching for 6 hours and I can't seem to find the issue with this GNU make file, everytime I try to compile by main.o by the order

```
make main.o
```

it gives me this error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c main.c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -- 
specs=nosys.specs  -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99 -o main.o
main.c:23:22: fatal error: platform.h: No such file or directory
#include "platform.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:52: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

makefile:

```
include sources.mk

# Platform Overrides
PLATFORM = MSP432

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs

# Compiler Flags and Defines
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
TARGET = c1m1
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS)  -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99
CPPFLAGs =


.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET).out

.PHONY: clean
clean:  
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).map

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

sources.mk:

```
# Add your Source files to this variable
SOURCES =./main.c \
    ./memory.c \
    ./startup_msp432p401r_gcc.c \
    ./system_msp432p401r.c  \
    ./interrupts_msp432p401r_gcc.c  



# Add your include paths to this variable
INCLUDES =-I./include/CMSIS \
    -I./include/common \
    -I./include/msp432
```

here's my code on github:

[github repository](https://github.com/Mahmoud5Saad/so.git)

Comment: Unclear what's going on with the `else` related error, but your compilation clearly doesn't know where `platform.h` is. You need to tell the compiler where to search for it since it's in a subfolder.

Comment: sources.mk has some defines in there for the includes, but its not added to the CFLAGS, so to find the includes at least you will need to add $(INCLUDES) to the CFLAGS variable

Comment: There's no "else" at line 32 of the Makefile in your GitHub, and there's no line 61 at all, so clearly the output you're showing is not from running `make` with that makefile.

Comment: sorry for that madscientist, I edited the error, and made sure github and error are matching and uptodate with code.

Comment: @lostbard I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: You should place all information necessary to answer the question in the question - external links to transient information does not make for a good SO question. The error message is emitted by the C pre-processor and is nothing to to with make.  The command line does not include any `-I<path>` directives.  For `platform.h` in this case at least you need `-I ./include/common`, but there are other headers in other paths that will also need resolving.

Comment: @Clifford ask for any information and I will give it, as I don't know what kind of information is needed. the
    -I./include/common
is added in the variable INCLUDES in sources.mk, and even when I copy platform.h to the main repo directory it doesn't compile. any thoughts?

Comment: Being in INCLUDES does not solve the problem - it is not magic; you have to use the macro to build the command line.  Clearly the `arm-none-eabi ...` command issued by `make` does not use `INCLUDES`.  To be clear `make` is not responsible for finding the header file; it simply emits the build commands - it is the pre-processor (executed by the compiler driver) that is failing to find the header.

Comment: The information necessary here in this case is the `makefile` and `sources.mk` content.

Comment: they are available and organized on the hub, could you check them?

Comment: No - as I said, that is not how SO works.  Useful questions will likely survive longer that your code might remain on github.  Or worse your code on github will be corrected and the question will no longer make any sense.  However it is now academic - I have fixed the question for you.

Comment: I got your point, I will definitely make my questions more useful in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used the `INCLUDES` macro in makefile's `CFLAGS` macro.  Consequently the `arm-none-eabi-gcc ...` command line does not specify the include paths to the compiler (or strictly the pre-processor).

```
CFLAGS = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) $(INCLUDES) -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I did and here's the error I get

    arm-none-eabi-gcc -c main.c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -- 
    specs=nosys.specs --I ./include/CMSIS -I ./include/common -I 
    ./include/msp432  -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99 -o main.o
    arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--I'; did you 
    mean '-I'?
    Makefile:52: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: @MahmoudSaad : Fine, so the change _did_ work (not as you suggested in an earlier comment).  What you have now is clearly a _different_ error.  You need to ask a different question if you cannot resolve it.  The problem however is that you have erroneously added a `-` somewhere.  My guess is that you have `-$(INCLUDES)` rather then just `$(INCLUDES)`.  `INCLUDES` is not a single option, and already has `-` in the individual directives in contains.

Comment: oooooh, I get it now, I was adding a minus sign before $(INCLUDES), after I removed it this error is solved but I have a new error, I will do my research and solve it.

Thanks sir for your guidance.  I will definitly keep what I learned here today in mind specially about asking useful questions.

Comment: @lostbard Since there is only one correct answer, it can be no surprise that they look the same!  Comments should not be used for posting answers, and in a true answer it is possible to be much clearer. You were free to post your own answer, and probably should have.